# Anaconda Saving to existing excel file

Tags: python, excel, anaconda

I have written a a short program in Python to save a dataframe into an existing excel file. it goes as follows:

```
def Save_To_Excel(self, path_save, df, sheet_name, startrow, startcol):    
    self.path = path_save
    self.df = df
    self.startrow = startrow
    self.startcol = startcol
    self.sheet_name=sheet_name

    #writer = pd.ExcelWriter(self.path, engine = 'openpyxl')
    #self.df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = self.sheet_name, index='False')
    book = load_workbook(self.path)
    with pd.ExcelWriter(self.path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
        writer.book = book
        writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)    
        self.df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=self.sheet_name, starrow=self.startrow, startcol=self.startcol)      

 #   with pd.ExcelWriter(self.path, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:  
 #       self.df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=self.sheet_name, starrow=self.startrow, startcol=self.startcol)      

    writer.save() 
    writer.close()
```

However I get the following error message:

File "C:\Users...\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 78, in _validate_archive
    file_format = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1].lower()

File "C:\Users...\Anaconda3\lib\ntpath.py", line 202, in splitext
    p = os.fspath(p)

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not DataFrame
Do anyone have any idea what is wrong with the code?

Comment: are you trying to save data frame into an excel file?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to save data in a dataframe object into an existing excel file.

Comment: can you share the dataframe

Comment: and maybe the rest of the code as well, cant see what inputs you're using into the function

Comment: d = Read_Excel.Read(source + 'F_G.xls', "B:I", 'Date', firstrow-2, 0, 'Blad1', lastrow-firstrow)
data = d.Import_From_Excel()
HY_Spread= data.iloc[:,[5]]

d.Save_To_Excel(HY_Spread, r"C:\....\Databas\test.xlsx", 'Blad1', 5, 5)

Comment: Its a timeserie with two columns where the first column is dates and the second is the US High Yield spread.

Comment: which part of your code is line 78?

Comment: seems like you put a dataframe into a filepointer

Comment: line 78 is as follows:        file_format = os.path.splitext(filename)[-1].lower()
        if file_format not in SUPPORTED_FORMATS: